# Setting an entity's key in NDB in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How do I set an `entity`'s key in my code.

Example, I have a user class

```
class User(ndb.Model)
  email
```

I want to be able to set email property and query using email property

`my_user = User(email='xyz@ab.com')`

Above statement sets email property, but Google App Engine generates its own key.

Can I set the key using User(key='xyz@ab.com')

If I can set the key property in a entity, how do I query for an entity using the key

Does this work
User.query(key='xyz@ab.com').get()

I realize that I can query using `email` as a property, but unfortunately I can't do that in context of a `transaction`.

That is the reason I am asking how to get(), set() by keys.

Also, when I end up querying by properties, I need to create indexes on properties, which I know will be unique

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's not `my_user = User(key='xyz@ab.com')`, it's:

```
my_user = User(id='xyz@ab.com')
my_user_key = my_user.put()
```

Now, `my_user_key` is the key, so you can get it by:

```
the_user_entity = my_user_key.get()
```

Or, later, you can get it by constructing a Key:

```
my_user_key = ndb.Key(User, id='xyz@ab.com')
the_user_entity = my_user_key.get()
```

or directly by:

```
User.get_by_id('xyz@ab.com')
```

Comment: Thanks! 

How do I query for user with email 'xyz@abc.om'

User.query(id='xyz@ab.com').get() ,or User.get_by_id('xyz@ab.com')>

Does App engine have indices on `id` property automatically, or should I include a index in index.yaml for 'id' property

Comment: Yes, the key is indexed on every entity, else it would not be queryable.  Either of the methods in my answer work (using `get()` from a Key, or `get_by_id()`. A query is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: Thanks! How do I access `id` property on ndb.Model object. If I have a user object, doing user.id gives an error saying User(ndb.Model) has no attribute `id`

Comment: `user.key.id()`

Comment: Beware that using the email address as ID adds issues if the user wants to change their email address later.